# equivalence of brace expansion within bash [[ compound command (test statement)

Tags: regex, bash, conditional-operator, brace-expansion

I want `foo()` compliant with an [extended regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) or like [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion).

Solution based on `egrep`:

```
foo() 
{
  egrep -sq "$2" <<< "$1" && echo "string '$1' matches pattern '$2'"
}

$ foo bar '.*r'
string 'bar' matches pattern '*r'
$ foo bar '.*r|.*s'
string 'bar' matches pattern '*r|*s'
```

But I also want a 100% `bash` solution. My attempt:

```
foo() 
{
  [[ "$1" = $2 ]] && echo "string '$1' matches pattern '$2'"
}
```

Basic pattern is OK:

```
$ foo bar '*r'
string 'bar' matches pattern '*r'
```

But what is the appropriate formatting to use to detect [alternation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Alternation-Operator.html) / [extended pattern](http://davitenio.wordpress.com/2008/09/14/bash-extended-pattern-matching/)?

```
$ foo bar '*(r|s)'
$ foo bar '*\(r|s\)'
$ foo bar '*\(r\|s\)'
$ foo bar '*\{r,s\}'
$ foo bar '*{r,s}'
```

Moreover `bash` manpage says:

> **[[ expression ]]** 
>   Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the words
>   between the [[ and ]]; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, 
>   arithmetic expansion, command substitution, process substitution, and
>   quote removal are  performed.

1. **Is there a trick to use extended regex/pattern within `[[ ]]` statement?**
2. **How would you implement a such function?**

Comment: None of the examples you show starting with `*` are valid regular expressions.

Comment: Oops you are right! Good point @chepner. I was thinking that pattern was a subset of regex! I fixed my question adding informative/educational links. Thanks for your vigilance. Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `=~` operator.

From `man bash`:

> An  additional  binary  operator, =~, is available, with the same
>   precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to  the  right 
>   of  the operator  is  considered  an  extended  regular  expression 
>   and matched accordingly.

Try this:

```
foo() 
{
  [[ "$1" =~ $2 ]] && echo "string '$1' matches pattern '$2'"
}
```

Also note that `*` is a wildcard (and undergoes "pattern matching") while `.*` is a regular expression.

Change your example to:

```
$ foo bar '.*(r|s)'
string 'bar' matches pattern '.*(r|s)'
```

Comment: This is wrong. ``=~`` doesn't check if it matches the pattern, it checks if this string contains a string that matches the pattern. So using regex ``.*(r|s)`` should return true for string ``asshole``. Use ``^pattern$`` instead for full matching

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
[[ 'bar' == *[rs] ]] && echo yes || echo no # this is simple globbing
```

Or using extglobs:

```
shopt -s extglob
[[ 'bar' == @(*r|*s) ]] && echo yes || echo no
```

For more info you can read [bash hackers page about pattern matching](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern)